# Comparing 2 Tables in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

Working on a way to compare 2 tables in PowerBI.

I'm joining the 2 tables using the primary key and making custom columns that compare if the old and new are equal.

This doesn't seem like the most efficient way of doing things, and I can't even color code the matrix because some values aren't integers.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a big project like this last year, comparing two versions of a data warehouse (SQL database).

I tackled most of it in the Query Editor (actually using Power Query for Excel, but that's the same as PBI's Query Editor).

My key technique was to first create a Query for each table, and use **Unpivot Other Columns** on everything apart from the Primary Key columns. This transforms it into rows of **Attribute, Value**.  You can filter **Attribute** to just the columns you want to compare.

Then in a new Query you can Merge & Expand the "old" and "new" Queries, joining on on the Primary Key columns + the Attribute column.  Then add Filter or Add Column steps to get to your final output.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!